# Get selected option from the tag <select> in php to use on if

Tags: php, html, select, post, if-statement

I tried this code:

```
<select name="selectedOption">
    <option value="select">  Select  </option>
    <option value="option1">  option 1  </option>
    <option value="option2">  option 2  </option>
</select>
<?php $selectedOption = $_POST['selectedOption']; ?>
<?php if($selectedOption == "option1") : ?>
    <a href="#">This will only display if option 1 selected</a>
<?php elseif($selectedOption == "option2") : ?>
    <a href="#">This will only display if option 2 selected</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But I get errors when I'm testing it on the web.
The error that apears is "Notice: Undefined index: selectedOption in C:\wamp\www\vilaLuz\index.php on line 40"

What I am trying to do is get the option from the select and put a text under if option 1 is selected and a different text under if option 2 is selected, is that possible?

Comment: php doesnt work this way, you should use javascript or if you insist on using php you need Ajax for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<select name="selectedOption">
    <option value="select">  Select  </option>
    <option value="option1">  option 1  </option>
    <option value="option2">  option 2  </option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="post"/>
</form>
<?php if(isset($_POST['selectedOption'])) : ?>
<?php $selectedOption = $_POST['selectedOption']; ?>
<?php if($selectedOption == "option1") : ?>
    <a href="#">This will only display if option 1 selected</a>
<?php elseif($selectedOption == "option2") : ?>
    <a href="#">This will only display if option 2 selected</a>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: he wasn't correctly formated. Apparently you can't right <?php endif; ?> as text it has to be in code format or it will not appear.

Comment: accepting my answer will be greatly appreciated. click on the "v" button under the downvote button

Answer (score 0):

If you have not send your form, $_POST['selectedOption'] will be not set and empty!

So;

```
<?php $selectedOption = (!empty($_POST['selectedOption']) ? $_POST['selectedOption'] : ''); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first check whether `$_POST['selectedOption']` exists using `isset`:

```
<?php
    $selectedOption = isset($_POST['selectedOption'])
                    ? $_POST['selectedOption']
                    : false;
?>
```

This is a ternary `if` statement which sets the value of `$selectedOption` to either the value of `$_POST['selectedOption']` if it is set, or `false` if it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You should check to see if $_POST['selectedOption'] is set and is not empty. Empty() does these tests for you.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['selectedOption'])) {
    $selectedOption = $_POST['selectedOption'];
    if($selectedOption == "option1") {
        echo('<a href="#">This will only display if option 1 selected</a>');
    }
    elseif($selectedOption == "option2"){
        echo('<a href="#">This will only display if option 2 selected</a>');
    }
}
?>
```